# How to measure Big O time complexity for deletion method of a Treeset?

Tags: java, big-o, treeset, jmh

I want to use JMH to prove the time complexity of adding to/ deleting from a Treeset in a Java orderbook, it should be O(log n) for insertion and deletion.

For insertion it is independent, as N grows it is not reliant on other messages. However for deletion, the orders need to be added in the first instance in order to be deleted. When performing the benchmarking if I was to preload all of the Orders, the Treeset will be full to begin with so it would not be realistic. Do I need to just process all messages in the same order they came, then run without the deletes and compare the times?

Is N the number of deletes or the size of the Treeset?

Comment: Why? You don’t need to prove it. It’s specified, and the behaviour of the algorithm is already analyzed and well-known.

Comment: "Is N the number of deletes or the size of the Treeset?" ... if you do k operations, just looking at each piece of data once gets you `O(k)`. The `O(log N)` above is one operation in terms of the size of the tree.

Comment: *"I want to use JMH to prove the time complexity of"*: It is a misconception to think that with benchmarking you can prove time complexity. Time complexity is about asymptotic behaviour and so it cannot be proven with inputs of certain sizes. It needs a mathematical approach. The most you can achieve with benchmarking is to *illustrate* a known time complexity... but it proves nothing.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, decided against this idea in the end.